# If SinA= SinB what does A equal

Tags: trigonometry

I know that if Tan A =Tan B then A = B + nπ

This is because Tan has a periodicity of π

What is the equivalent formula for Sin A = Sin B and Cos A = Cos B

Please explain also why these formulas are true

Comment: $\sin(a+2n\pi) = \sin a \cos (2n\pi) + \cos a \sin(2n\pi) = \sin a, \ \ \ \ \cos (a+2n\pi) = \cos a \cos(2n\pi) - \sin a \sin (2n\pi) = \cos(a)$

Comment: Think of drawing a horizontal line where sinA is noting where it intersects with sin(x) function. Then mark the points on x axis that it crosses. what do you notice about the length between these points, they should all be the same length apart

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Using  Prosthaphaeresis Formulas](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ProsthaphaeresisFormulas.html),

$$\sin A-\sin B=0\iff2\sin\frac{A-B}2\cos\frac{A+B}2=0$$

If $\sin\dfrac{A-B}2=0\implies\dfrac{A-B}2=m\pi\iff A=2m\pi+B$

If $\cos\dfrac{A+B}2=0\implies\dfrac{A+B}2=(2m+1)\dfrac\pi2\iff A=2m\pi+\pi-B$

Similarly,  we can derive $\cos A-\cos B=0\implies A=2r\pi\pm B$

where $m,r$ are any integers

Can you take it home from here?

Answer (score 1):

$ A = 2n\pi + B $ since $ Sin $ and $Cos$ has a period $2n\pi$

Comment: There are also two other cases. See my answer.

Comment: Sin A = Sin B. Also, Sin B = Sin (π – B). Thus, it is possible to have A = π – B. I don’t see how the above result can be generated from your formula.

Answer (score 1):

$\sin A=\sin B$ gives $$A=B+2n\pi \vee A=\pi-B+2n\pi$$

$\cos A=\cos B$ gives $$A=B+2n\pi \vee A=-B+2n\pi$$

(for $n\in\mathbb{Z}$)

---

**Explanation**

For $\sin A=\sin B$, think of two angles in the unit circle. Sine is the $y$-coordinate, so either the angles are the same (first case) or we seek the other angle that has the same $y$-coordinate (second case).

The same for $\cos A=\cos B$, think of two angles in the unit circle. Cosine is the $x$-coordinate, so either the angles are the same (first case) or we seek the other angle that has the same $x$-coordinate (second case).

Answer (score 0):

$A=B+2k\pi$ or $A=\pi−B+2k\pi$ with $k\in\mathbb{Z}$ for $\sin(A)=\sin(B)$.

$A=B+2k\pi$ or $A=−B+2k\pi$ with $k\in\mathbb{Z}$ for $\cos(A)=\cos(B)$.

As stated in the comments, this can easily be seen by drawing the function and a horizontal line intersecting the function.